# Can't resolve react-number-picker

Tags: reactjs

I import 'react-number-picker' but I can't find module. This is error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-number-picker'. 'c:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/programacion-3-2019-arias/cliente/node_modules/react-number-picker/dist/react-number-picker.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/react-number-picker` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-number-picker';`ts(7016)

Anyone has got same problem as me?

Comment: I can think about running `npm install @types/react-number-picker` first from the error message. Can you clarify if you did that before? Thanks!

Comment: I've tried about everything; putting import react-number-picker/src or copying NumberPicker.jsx and pasting in react-number-picker/dist but I'm getting same error.

Comment: Yes. I did that before. But it not works. I put on the log "npm install @types/react-number-picker" but I'm getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `tsconfig.json` file and under `compilerOptions`  add this line `"noImplicitAny": false`. If it is set to true change it to false. This makes sure to allow imports for non typed third party libraries.

```
"compilerOptions": {
 ...other options here
"noImplicitAny": false
 },
```

Comment: where is my tsconfig.json?, inside none_modules or same route like my package.json?

Comment: First thing are you using typescript with react? and are you using create-react-app? If so you should have the file in root folder along with package.json. If you are not using CRA then you need to create one

Comment: Yes. I'm using create-react-app cause I created project in gitlab.com and cloned it. And added that line but I've got same error. I've got my tsconfig.json and my package.json in same folder.

Comment: I have added the answer. Add the noImplicitAny to the compilerOptions object like I did above